# How to set css margin/padding to a child div based on its own width, and not of parent?

Tags: html, css, margin

For ex:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, normally if I give margin as 20%, it is 20% of parent's width. But I want child to have margin calculated based on its own width. Is it possible by any chance?

**Edit:**

[image: MarginForChild]

The (Orange)Margin should be calculated based on width of (Green)Child. I.e. Wider the Green Box, more the Margin. (Or less in my case).

Basically Similar to `margin:auto`. But I don't want to use that, since we don't want to align it exactly in center.

Comment: How is the width of the child set? I mean if you explicitly set the pixel width in CSS, you could set the margin to a specific number of pixels in CSS (ie - 20% of whatever) and just forget the whole percent thing.  If you don't explicitly set width for the child, then you could easily write some javascript to calculate the width of the child, and then set the margin appropriately. Let me know if you want to go this route.

Comment: Relative units: %, em, rem, vh, vw  Absolute units: px, pt   All relative units must have something to compare to, AFAIK using  px will definitely allow an element to stand on it's own. If you want flexibility but more control, try using rem for small scale and vh and vw for large scale.

Comment: Without a screenshot or a doodle even, I can't really tell what you are asking. It sounds easy enough as to just adding margin to the child but that would be too simple.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you nest the child div inside the parent div, the child div's attributes will be relative to the parent div's attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Use an invisible `div`.

E.g. if you want to set a margin to the left of 20% of the child div, just set width of child to 84% and width of the div to 16%.
Also, use `id`, not `class`:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div id="child">...</div>
</div>
```

and in `style.css`:

```
.invisible {
  display:none;
}
```

Also, set `display` of the rest of the `div`s to `inline-block` to get them to align horizontally.

Answer (score -1):

Set parent Div with `position:relative` and margin in `%` and provide child element with fix `height` and `width` in `pixel` and also, `margin` with `pixel`
or 
second way, set parent div with `position relative` and provide child element with `position absolute` and set `left right and width`